# Copying static value into non static instance

Tags: java, static, copy, instance

I want to create a system for keeping track of instances of a class. I would like to do this by using a static variable to keep track of the number of previous instances and then just setting an int equal to that number as the ID.

The problem that I am currently having is that I get this error: "Cannot make a static reference to non static field id"
This occurs when I'm trying to copy value from the static int to the instanced int.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int idCount = 0;
    public int id;

    public MyClass()
    {
        id = idCount;
        idCount++;
    }
}
```

Primarily I'm doing this so an object can identify itself in an array. If this is not the proper way of doing this It would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: `"Cannot make a static reference to non static field id"` - Impossible. This only happens when you make a reference to a non static field from a static method, not the other way around. [Try it](https://ideone.com/RFejOK)

Comment: your class compiles just fine... are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: You are missing the (static) code block in which you are getting this compile-time error

Comment: I am clearly bind, I have been looking at this code for so long I missed the static in the declaration of the un-simplified version of this. Thanks for the help>

Answer (score -1):

You can make this:

```
public class MyClass
{
public static int idCount = 0;
public int id;

public MyClass()
{
    id = idCount;
    MyClass.addCount();
}

static void addCount(){
   idCount++;
}

 static int getCount(){
   return idCount;
}
}
```

Comment: The code in the question works fine, it was just a mistake by the OP

Comment: Yeah it was a mistake by me, I'm just a tired idiot, there is an extra method in my actual code that contains the assignment and increment, and I accidentally put a static in the definition and didn't see it. Someone pointed out my error can only happen that way. But thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Elvermg Yes it works, but it doesn't answer the question. Which is basically "Why does this code produce a compiler error?", and the answer is "It doesn't".